# Append a div to each instance of another div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to add a new div.bio-wrapper to each instance of div.card-row on a page (there are currently 2 instances of card-row, but could be more). With jQuery, a simple appendTo works fine, but I don't know how to do this with vanilla JS, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Edit: The suggested solution is only adding .bio-wrapper to the last instance of .card-row, so I added the function that makes the card-row div below, in case it influences things

Here's what I have:

```
function buildGrid() {
  const cards = $('.team-grid .card');
   for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i+=3) {
    cards.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="card-row"></div>');
  }
}

buildGrid();

function bioContainer() {
  // jQuery version that works
  //$('<div class="bio-wrapper"></div>').appendTo('.card-row');

  // Vanilla version that only works on the first instance of .card-row
  const block_to_insert = document.createElement('div');
  block_to_insert.className = 'bio-wrapper';

  const container_block = document.querySelectorAll('.card-row');
  // Suggested by @eugene-sunic
  for (let i = 0; i < container_block.length; i++) {
    container_block[i].appendChild(block_to_insert);
  }
}
```

The resulting HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="card-row">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="bio-wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="card-row">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="bio-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Find all `.card-row`. 2) Loop each `.card-row`, and for each `.card-row`, create a new `.bio-wrapper` and append to current `.card-row`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

Once you've grabbed all the elements of class card-row, append the block to each one of them.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7bgqy9me/

HTML

```
<div id="main">

  <div class="card-row">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="bio-wrapper"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-row">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-row">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
function bioContainer() {
  const block_to_insert = document.createElement('div');
  block_to_insert.className = 'bio-wrapper';

  const container_block = document.querySelectorAll('.card-row');
  for (let i = 0; i < container_block.length; i++) {
    container_block[i].appendChild(block_to_insert);
  }
}

bioContainer()
console.log(document.getElementById('main').innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create the new bio-wrapper div inside the for loop, otherwise it only creates 1 instance of the bio-wrapper.

Here's the working loop:

```
let block_to_insert;
const container_block = document.querySelectorAll( '.card-row' );

for(let i = 0; i < container_block.length; i++) {
  block_to_insert = document.createElement('div');
  block_to_insert.className = 'bio-wrapper';

  container_block[i].appendChild(block_to_insert);
}
```